# How to edit specific number in array which is converted from string in s

Tags: javascript, sql, actionscript-3

I have a game (javascript) in which players can collect fruits ( apples, banana, Orange).
Apples id is 1 and 2 for banana and 3 for oranges
All these information are recorded in one field in sql which is called "fruits" in users table.
The player can only collect 3 fruits of the same kind as maximum

For example if a player got 3 apples, 3 bananas, 1 Oranges it will be recorded as :
1:3 ,2:3 , 3:1

The problem is if he will collect another Orange it must be recorded like that :
1:3 ,2:3 , 3:2

But its recorded like that :

1:3 ,2:3 , 3:0 , 3:1

So I convert this field from String to array by split(",")

But

Returning to the example how can I code it to search in the field for number 3 ( which is Oranges number) and edit the number after it ( 1 to 2 as in example) and save the rest ( number of apples and bananas)

Knowing that fruits number has no specific arrangement in the field

It can be recorded like :

2:3 ,1:3 ,3:1

Depending on which fruit is collceted frist by the player.

Comment: Show us the code you are using and where you are stuck in it

Answer (score 1):

```js
const IDs = { // Store ID references
  "apple" : 1,
  "banana": 2,
  "orange": 3,
};

const max = 3;
const basket = {};

const collect = (item) => {
  if (!IDs.hasOwnProperty(item)) return; // No such item
  const id = IDs[item];
  if (!basket[id]) basket[id] = 0; // Set to 0 if was not existent
  if (basket[id] === max ) { // Throw an error if max
    return alert(`You already have ${max} ${item}s`);
  }
  basket[id] += 1; // Increment if no alerts
};

collect("apple");
collect("banana");
collect("apple");
collect("apple");
collect("apple"); // Should give an error

console.log(basket); // Let's see what we have in the basket so far
```